# js modules: newly created HTML-Element appears how it should. But doesnt have the assigned EventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, module, event-listener

i use modules for this work.it is supposed to become a programm, where you can create and learn virtual vocabulary cards.

this is my main.js:

```
import {Mainmenu} from "./aggregator.js";

let mainmenu = new Mainmenu();
mainmenu.start();
```

mainmenu.start() creates the html basis of my page:

```
start() {
        let _body = document.querySelector("body");
        _body.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin" , this.createMainmenu());
        _body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend" , this.createHomeButton());
    }
```

createMainMenu creates two Buttons, of which one gets an EventListener:

mainmenu.createMainmenu():

```
[...]
let _mFrameButtonEditVokabs = document.createElement("button");
                _mFrameButtonEditVokabs.setAttribute("id" , "mFrameButtonEditVokabs");
                _mFrameButtonEditVokabs.innerText = "Sets bearbeiten";
                _mFrameButtonEditVokabs.addEventListener("click" , (e) => {
                    try {
                        _toggleFrame.erstelleToggleFrame();
                    }
                    catch {
                        let _toggleFrame = new Toggleframe();
                        _toggleFrame.erstelleToggleFrame();
                    }
                    e.target.classList.toggle("buttonsClicked");
                    setTimeout(() => e.target.classList.toggle("buttonsClicked"), 300);
                    _masterFrame.style.transform = "translateX(-50%)";

                    document.getElementById("homeButton").style.transform = "translateX(200%)";
                });

            _main.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin" , _mFrameButtonLearnVokabs);
            _main.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend" , _mFrameButtonEditVokabs);

        _mainFrame.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin" , _header);
        _mainFrame.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend" , _main);

        let _toggleFrame = document.createElement("div");
        _toggleFrame.setAttribute("id" , "toggleFrame");

        _masterFrame.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin" , _mainFrame);
        _mainFrame.insertAdjacentElement("afterend" , _toggleFrame);

        return _masterFrame;
```

AND THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FINE. I get my button, it gets its eventListener AND THE LISTENER WORKS.

Now comes the fun part, that makes me rethink my choices of becoming a programmer:

I also create a homeButton WITH EXACT THE SAME TECHNIQUE, BUT IT HAS NO EVENTLISTENER!!

mainmenu.createHomeButton() creates the Homebutton:

mainmenu.createHomeButton():

```
createHomeButton() {
        let _homeButton = document.createElement("div");
        _homeButton.setAttribute("id" , "homeButton");
        _homeButton.addEventListener("click" , () => {
            console.log("Home wurde geklickt");
        });
        return _homeButton;
    }
```

Two HTML Elements, the same kind of creating them, setting their attributes and setting an Eventlistener. The first one works, the other one doesnt. Why?

Comment: I [can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/L6qchu85/) with the given code ..?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @James : ´_body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend" , this.createHomeButton());´ isnt that the third step?

Teemu:        want me to send you the complete Code?

Comment: It looks like all the related parts are already in the question, you could create a [mre], though. You've to check, that your current code really matches to what you've posted. And define "_it doesn't work_", what does that mean? The button doesn't appear on the page? The event listener doesn't fire? Something else?

Comment: the homebutton appears, but the eventlistener doesnt fire? when i check the inspector in the development-window of my browser, i can see that the homebutton doesnt even HAVE an eventListener.

edit: I changed the title of the question and made the issue within it clearer, thanks for the information

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't scroll up enough.

Comment: Make sure you're not removing the event listener from the element at some point later. If that's not the case, the inspected element on the page is not the element `createHomeButton` creates and `start` method inserts to the DOM (ex. setting `innerHTML` of the parent element will remove all the attached listeners from the elements inside the parent). You've to check what else is inserted (also check CSS for overlaying elements).

Comment: For those who are interested in this issue: i fount the mistake, but i have no explanation how it relates to the eventListener of the homeButton:

within mainmenu.createMainmenu() within the assignment of an EventListener FOR THE other HTML Element, i (for some reason) had a statement to transform the homebutton within the x-axe. I removed this statement and put it in another method and suddenly the eventListener was there